# Dynamically Creating the Select List using php MySql but selecting an option is not working

Tags: php, mysql

I'm fetching the select list from MySql database that is getting displayed as a select box, that is fine. Meanwhile, I'm trying to select a particular option from the select box using php, which is not working and I really don't know why :( . Here is the code :

```
$route = "CLIFTON";                 
echo "<form>";
echo "<select>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_route))
{
    echo "<option ";
        if (isset($route))
        {
            if ($route == $row['route'])
            {
                echo "selected='selected'";
            }
        }
        echo ">";
        echo $row['route'];
    echo "</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
echo "</form>";
```

Suppose there are several routes that are fetched from database to a select box, one of which contains a value i.e. `CLIFTON`, also I've defined a value "CLIFTON" in `$route` variable for convenience.So far, I've concluded that when it reaches the point : `if ("CLIFTON" == "CLIFTON")` , it should echo the selected attribute and the option is not getting selected.
My Question is that why is it not getting inside the if block? I'm really stuck on that :( , anyone please help me? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: you might need a little jQuery / aJax to display the values `live` - if you're not using any of those, I can then assume you're posting the form to a page, which will not work because your above html structure is incomplete...

Comment: Sir, I appreciate your idea, but if there is a requirement to implement without using jquery/ajax, how would I do that using just php/MySql, I've done this so many times but this time I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: as your code stands, it should be working. I would say, verify the data that is being returned from the DB. For the fun of it, replace `$route == $row['route']` with `$route == 'CLIFTON'` and see what happens

Comment: Yes, the If block works now, it is displaying the selected attribute but why is it not reading the same value as in variable?

Comment: That means you need to verify the data that's in the DB table, and or verify the `$row['route']` output /  the `Query` that's in `$get_route`

Comment: Dump each row as you loop.  Are these as you would expect?

Comment: @andre3wap I found it, I've answered it below, thanks for your precious time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I somehow resolved the issue, the problem was in the string that I was fetching from database, it was not getting inside the if block because of the blank space in the string, comparing ("CLIFTON" == "CLIFTON ") was returning false, I did not notice that blank space. So, I added the following just before comparing the two :

```
$row['route'] = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $row['route']);
```

For better performance :

```
$row['route'] = trim($row['route']);
```

That space thing took a day of me, but thanks anyway everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

You can take each option in single variable like this:

```
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_route))
     {
      $option = ""; 
      $option = "<option ";
            if (isset($route))
            {
                if ($route == $row['route'])
                {
                    $option .= "selected='selected'";
                }
            }
            $option .= ">";
            $option .= $row['route'];
        $option .= "</option>";
        echo $option;
     }
```

Comment: Sir, I tried your code but no gain :( , have you checked it? Is It working on your side?

Comment: There might be some error inside your if condition. Check printing something inside the if condition of ($route == $row['route'])

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine as per what you are expecting.

I think the problem is It's not reaching this condition

`if ($route == $row['route'])
   {
      die("Here");
      echo "selected='selected'";
   }`

Check to see If your code is reaching inside this condition. That is your condition is true. If It's so then It would show the item selected. No errors in the code itself. Place the `die()` function to test weather the condition is satisfied or not.